# Redirect urls with directory after file extensions in url [htaccess]

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have urls like this: 
my-site.com/index.php/2014.

I want to remove this url's and redirect all of them to my root domain.
Google is indexed a lot of this url's and my rank is very low. They judging me by content.

Every url with / after php file extensions I want to redirect to my root domain.

example: **index.php/2004 -> index.php**,
**team.php/2004/2004 -> team.php**
and etc...

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/index\.php/(.+)$ http://example.com/index.php

RedirectMatch 301 ^/team\.php/(.+)$ http://example.com/team.php
```

Edit :

You can also  redirect your urls with just a single line of Redirect  :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^.]+)\.php/(.+)$ http://example.com/$1.php
```

Comment: Thanks, its workng, but there is a chance to not write the names of pages, something automatically?